# Pronunciation in medical terminology

Tags: pronunciation, terminology, stress, medicine

I have been arguing about this with quite a number of people and it seems we all cannot find the answer (med students, duh)

My question is: Where should the stress on words like mastoideus and styloideus be? on Ideus or idEus.

Comment: Are you asking where the stress would be if a Roman or Greek were saying it (not particularly useful in my opinion, but others may disagree), or what the norms for how medical professionals say it? For the latter, it could be worth listening to lectures online which might mention the words. If your tutors pronounce it in different ways it's a sign that you don't need to worry about it too much!

Comment: I am asking how a Roman or Greek would say it. I have listened to many medical professionals in person (some of them german, others bulgarian) and online (mostly british) and I hear vast differences every time. That's why I am interested in what it would Actually have sounded like.

Comment: The reason I worry about it is that some of my tutors and even professors have a habbit of writing/saying the names of structures blatantly incorrectly, while at the same time aömost literally worshipping the "Terminologia anatomica" 

Comment: You may want to take a look at section 3.4 in this textbook (p. 23). Medical Latin is not quite the same as Classical Latin. https://www.scribd.com/document/251246867/Medical-Latin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are no classical precedents for the specific form of the ending *-oideus.* It ultimately comes from Ancient Greek *-οειδής,* an ending found mostly on third-declension adjectives with the meaning "-shaped" or "-like". These adjectives are compounds containing the linking vowel -ο- followed by the element εἶδος "form, shape". The direct Latinization of this Greek ending is *-oides.* How this was altered to *-oideus* is difficult for me to explain. I couldn't think of any other similar examples of Greek *-ης* corresponding to Latin *-eus,* but when browsing this site, I found a previous question where [Cairnarvon's answer states that *eugenēus/eugenīus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/16335/9) is a Latinization of Greek εὐγενής.

Looking through [all the Greek words containing -οειδ- in the LSJ Dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=substring&lookup=oeid&lang=greek), I only found a few ending in anything other than -ο-ειδής, and none with an ending comparable to *-oideus.* So I think the extension of the Greek ending with *-eus* must have been created in Latin. But there are also [no words ending in "oideus" in Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=substring&lookup=oideus&lang=la), so "-oideus" seems to be a post-Classical formation, possibly occurring exclusively in "anatomical Latin".

#### Latin stress is predictable based on vowel length

Latin stress, which is what would be most relevant here (since the ending *-us* is Latinate or Latinized), is (almost always) predictable if you know the length of the vowel in the second-to-last syllable of a word.

- If the e is short, the Latin pronunciation would stress the i (which represents the Greek diphthong ει, and which did not form a diphthong in Latin with the preceding o, despite the usual English pronunciation of *-oi-* as a diphthong in the ending *-oid*). So the stress would be -o-í-de-us.
- If the e is long, the Latin pronunciation would stress the e. So the stress would be o-i-dé-us.

#### Is the e short or long?

Unfortunately, it's quite unclear to me what length this *e* "should" be.

Latin has both words ending in *-ĕus* with short e and words ending in *-ēus* with long e.

- The ending *-ĕus* is a common Latin adjective-forming suffix.
- The ending *-ēus* is less common. It [violates the general rule that a vowel before another vowel is short](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/14259/vowel-shortening-before-another-vowel-exceptions), but can be found nevertheless in a fair number of words, such as *[Bacchēus](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/Baccheus)*. I believe *Bacchēus* is derived from Greek [Βάκχειος/Βακχεῖος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3D*ba%2Fkxeios), meaning what we see here is an example of Greek ει before a vowel being Latinized as long ē. I think most other words ending in *-ēus* have the same origin in Greek -ειος. Another example: *[spondēus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dspondeus)*
- (Some words can end in -e͡us, with a diphthong eu, but I'm pretty sure that's only used for words where *-eus* is from Greek -ευς, and so it would be implausible in *-oideus* words.)

So which do we find in words ending in *-oideus*?

Based on what I've read, I would lean towards the pronunciation with a short e and stress on the i. I have found an article, "[Medical Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=RLJXAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA443)" by H. Zimmerer in the *Medical Brief* (Vol. 36, 1908), that argues for this interpretation of the form, while also showing that variability in the accentuation of the ending has existed for more than a century:

> By far the most frequent of all adjectival suffixes in medical onomatology is -ideus *-ο- ειδής*. [...] Only in the seventeenth century they were used as Latin epithets in anatomy, mostly through J. Riolanus; many of them are still in use today. The corresponding Greek adjectives end in *-ειδής*. In Latin it is permissible to contract the diphthong *ει* to *ι* and to change the end syllable *ης* to -eus, so that, for instance, *αδεν-ο-ειδής* may be expressed by aden-o-ideus. In this word the i is long, because it stands for *ει*, while the e is short, as is the case in all adjectives in -eus (aureus, argenteus, ferreus, plumbeus, etc.). The only correct pronunciation, therefore, is adenoideus, and this also applies to the similar words adenoid, alcaloid, sarcoid, myxoid, etc., which have been formed in imitation of the Greek precept, and which ought to have the long accent on the i. It has become an objectionable practice among anatomists to reverse the accentuation, and the desire that such custom should no longer obtain, is voiced by all linguists.

(page 443)

I found the similarly formed word theoideus marked theoídeus in the dictionary *[Botanisch-Gärtnerisches Taschenwörterbuch](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&q=theoideus&id=SDkXAAAAYAAJ&output=text#v=onepage&q&f=false),* by Reinhold Metzner.

However, I don't know of a definite argument that the e cannot be long as *Bacchēus.* In fact, the previous question linked above about *eugenēus* seems to show an analogous example where a long vowel apparently was used (however, I'm not sure how the dictionary-makers actually know the vowel was long in that word).

I'm not familiar enough with the relevant rules for Greek word formation to be able to say whether it would theoretically be possible to derive forms in -οειδειος from -οειδής in Greek. In purely ***phonological*** terms, it looks possible to me, as adjectives like -οειδής have a stem ending in /es/, and the Greek sound change rules of deleting intervocalic /s/ and contracting adjacent vowels should turn -es-ios into -ειος. For comparison, it looks like there are a few [abstract nouns ending in -οείδεια](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=substring&lookup=oeidei&lang=greek), which would be the outcome of -o-eides-ia. And the name Ἀριστοφάνης, which I believe is etymologically a third-declension /es/ stem* like -οειδής adjectives, has the derived adjective Ἀριστοφάνειος. However, I don't know if it makes any ***morphological*** sense in Greek to attach the adjective-forming suffix -ios to a word that is already an adjective.

---

*Apparently [third-declension masculine ης nouns may have eventually shifted to the first declension](http://hellenisteukontos.blogspot.com/2009/05/analogy-in-third-declension-nominals.html), but I don't think that's relevant here

Comment: I want to thank you for the extensive and, honestly amazing answer to my question. Now I feel inspired to actually learn more about Greek and Latin inbetween and regardless of studying for exams.